# Способы получения информации из динамически формируемой HTML-страницы

Tags: автоматизация, dhtml

**Есть**

Сайт, который предоставляет определенного рода информацию (статистику), которая формируется и на сервере (посредством `php`), и на клиенте (посредством `javascript`, или его производных ... в виде фрэймворков). Простой `wget <url>` задачу не решает.

**Нужно**

Периодически снимать информацию и заносить ее в базу для формирования отчетности в виде графиков изменений. Снятие информации должно быть строго автоматически.

**Вопрос**

Какими средствами это возможно осуществить/запрограммировать? В моем распоряжении, вернее, чем я владею на данный момент: `С++/Qt5` выше среднего, `Perl5` в совершенстве, `Ruby` из разряда начинающего.

Операционная система значения не имеет. Windows/FreeBSD/Linux/OSX - это есть все в закромах оф родина. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Ruby on Rails, написав простенькое api-приложение которое будет с заданным промежутком вреиени выполнять запрос нужной страницы и, распарсив её, сохранять нужные данные. Gem-ы для этой задачи(в частности таймер) есть на github.

Comment: А как же исполнение javascript'ов на данной странице? Страница же частично формируется "на клиенте".

Comment: Ну, даже в этом случае данные в каком то формате приходят, правильно? Например придёт отдельно файлик с Json, его будет ещё легче распарсить

Comment: Не придет. Придет HTML-ка, в которой прописана куча скриптов. Собственно, которые браузер самостоятельно вытягивает, исполняет, и которые с помощью того же брайзера уже "тянут" данные. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Хм, хороший вопрос. Посмотрю подробнее, вечером отпишусь)

Comment: Я поразмышлял и пришел к выводу что если контент формирутся, в вашем случае, с помощью js, то он получается с сервера, скорее всего, отдельным запросом, так? Значит можно в консоли посмотреть какие запросы отправляются и увидеть в каком формат приходят данные(соответственно можно самому отправить такой запрос). Необходимости в выполнении js нет. Как-то так

Comment: Это мысль. Надо попробовать `winshark` натравить. Спасибо!